# How to get all Authorize Policies that I added in the Startup.ConfigureServices in Asp.Net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

In my Asp.NET Core WebApi application, I want to add permissions to the **properties in ViewModel**, and then customize an ActionFilter to filter the respone value. If the user does not have the permission, the property will be replaced by a callback value.
Now, I want to use Authorize Policy to check the permission.

**How to get all Authorize Policies that I added in the Startup.ConfigureServices?**

```
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (!(context.Result is JsonResult)) return;
        var c = (JsonResult)context.Result;
        var pas = c.Value
              .GetType().GetTypeInfo()
              .GetProperties()
              .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<PropertyPermissionAttribute>() != null)
              .Select(p =>
                {
                    var attr = p.GetCustomAttribute<PropertyPermissionAttribute>();
                    return (p, attr);
                });

        // ** How to Get All Policies ?? **


        foreach (var (p, a) in pas)
        {
            // Check Policies

            var cb = a.CallbackValue;
            if (cb!=null && p.PropertyType == cb.GetType())
            {
                p.SetValue(c.Value, cb);
            }
            else
            {
                p.SetValue(c.Value, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or is there **any other ways** to implement permissions at viewmodel's properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible. Policies are stored into private field. [See source](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationOptions.cs). However, I do not understand why you need all policies? You can get necessary policy from `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)` if you store the name of the policy in `PropertyPermissionAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks, that is it! But how can I check the User by the Policy?

Comment: [Through custom authorization handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased).

Comment: Probably because he wants to get a list of all available policies for a Site Admin to configure users via view.  That's at least what I wanted to do.  I do have matching db entries in AspNetUserClaims but querying those present doesn't give you a list of all potential claims/policies.

Comment: What did you end up doing? That's exactly what I want to do, list policies in a "role permission" admin panel so the admin can dynamically create roles and associate policies. In my case each policy has a single role claim. The only thing I'm missing is a way to display each policy by policy name. I could persist them in a static class, but it seems like duplication..

Comment: i ended up making a relatively fragile extension, with a addPolicyEx that forwards to addPolicy but also records the policies for later checking. For the dashboard case it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done and it builds on what @Ivan R was saying. I had to do exactly the same thing.

First create a Console app with a SecurityStartup class that inherits from your Startup class defined in your console application that houses your controllers. But first define a virtual method in your Startup class that houses your controllers

Eg:

```
protected virtual void OutputEndpointInfo(IServiceCollection services){ }
```

now call this method in the ConfigureServies method in Startup.cs

Eg:

```
OutputEndpointInfo(services);
```

Your SecurityStartup class should look something like:

```
public class SecurityStartup : Startup
{

    public static List<Endpoint> Endpoints{ get; set; }

    public SecurityStartup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment) : base(configuration, environment)
    {
        Endpoints = new List<Endpoint>();
    }

    protected override void OutputEndpointInfo(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var authorizationPolicyCollectionProvider = services
            .BuildServiceProvider()
            .GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider>();

        var actionDescriptorCollectionProvider = services
            .BuildServiceProvider()
            .GetRequiredService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();

        var actionDescriptors = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items;

        foreach (var actionDescriptor in actionDescriptors)
        {
            if (actionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)
            {
                string controllerName = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerName;
                string actionName = controllerActionDescriptor.ActionName;

                var endpoint = new Endpoint
                {
                    Controller = controllerName,
                    Action = actionName
                };

                AuthorizeAttribute? authoriseAttribute = null;
                var authorisation = (controllerActionDescriptor?.EndpointMetadata
                    .Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(AuthorizeAttribute)));

                if (authorisation != null && authorisation.Any())
                    authoriseAttribute = (AuthorizeAttribute)(authorisation).First();

                if (authoriseAttribute != null)
                {  
                    endpoint.Policy = authoriseAttribute.Policy;
                    if (endpoint.Policy != null)
                        endpoint.AuthorizationPolicy = authorizationPolicyCollectionProvider
                            .GetPolicyAsync(authoriseAttribute.Policy).Result;
                }

                Endpoints.Add(endpoint);
                Output.WriteLine(String.Empty, ConsoleColor.White);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with an Endpoint class:

```
public class Endpoint
{
    public string? Controller { get; set; }
    public string? Action { get; set; }
    public string? Policy { get; set; }

    public AuthorizationPolicy? AuthorizationPolicy { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your Console app have this code, it basically iterates through all the endpoints and creates a collection that contains all the Authorisation policies you setup in your controller application:

Eg:

```
_host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<SecurityStartup>();
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false);
            }).UseSerilog((hostContext, loggerConfig) =>
            {
                ServiceInstanceInfo serviceInstanceInfo = hostContext.Configuration.Get<ServiceInstanceInfo>();
            })
            .Build();

    await DisplayUserSecurityEndpointData();
```

with a method (I like to grab an access token from an STS for an authenticated user and check if they cam access each endpoint):

```
private static async Task DisplayUserSecurityEndpointData()
{
    var config = new SecurityConfig();
    var endpoints = SecurityStartup.Endpoints;
    var token = await SecurityService.GetAccessTokenPasswordFlow(config);
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token);
    var securityToken = jsonToken as JwtSecurityToken;
    var claims = securityToken.Claims.ToList();

    endpoints.ForEach(p => {
        Output.Write($"{p.Controller} {p.Action}");

        if (p.AuthorizationPolicy != null && p.AuthorizationPolicy.Requirements.First() is ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement)
        {
            var policyClaim = (ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement)p.AuthorizationPolicy.Requirements.First();
            bool hasAccess = claims.Any(q => q.Type == policyClaim.ClaimType);

            Output.Write($" ACCESS: {claims.Any(q => q.Type == policyClaim.ClaimType)}",
                hasAccess ? ConsoleColor.Green : ConsoleColor.Red);
        }
    });
}
```

Now running this will give a collection of every endpoint and all the Auth stuff including claims, roles etc

I've not included all the other classes etc - but you get the idea